# Get last viewed item from MySQL timestamp

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to retrieve the last viewed page from MySQL database, which is structured as followed:

`articles table`

```
  id |   title   | content |   created  
----------------------------------------
  1  |  title-1  |  info-1 | 1386478352 
  2  |  title-2  |  info-2 | 1386532855 
  3  |  title-3  |  info-3 | 1386637325 
  4  |  title-4  |  info-4 | 1386812249 
  5  |  title-5  |  info-5 | 1387094028
```

I'd like to get the last viewed page, not sure how much time would be enough as each time a page on the site refreshes this function would be called.. but, this is what I have tried but it does not return anything.

```
"SELECT * FROM articles WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, created,NOW()) < 10 LIMIT 2"
```

but as I said, it does not return a single data. This is how I am trying to print the information.

```
$loopOne = 0;
foreach($articleLastView as $recent)
{
    $recent_id          = $recent['id'];
    $recent_title       = $recent['title'];
    $recent_created     = $recent['created'];

    if ( $loopOne == 0 )
    {
        echo 'I print info here if result is the first';
    $loopOne++;
    } 
    else if( $loopOne == 1 )
    {
        echo 'I print info here if result is the second';
    $loopOne++;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but how is the column `created` related to the last viewing time? I would imagine that that field would contain the timestamp of when the article was created...

Comment: What are the desired results for the data you have provided?

Answer (score 2):

```
"SELECT * FROM `articles` ORDER BY `created` DESC LIMIT 1"
```

That should get the last viewed page.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this wouldn't accomplish what I need as I am trying to retrieve the last viewed article. Maybe I should have asked the question differently and used page_views instead as that would be better.

Comment: Sorry. I don't know why, but I was assuming the timestamp was the last time the article was viewed. I should have read the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason your function isn't working is that you're passing in a UNIX timestamp when the function expects two datetime expressions.

According to the [Doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff):

> **TIMESTAMPDIFF(unit,datetime_expr1,datetime_expr2)**
>
> Returns datetime_expr2 – datetime_expr1, where datetime_expr1 and
>   datetime_expr2 are date or datetime expressions.

Your first expression is a UNIX timestamp, but your `NOW()` expression is a datetime.

Try converting your UNIX timestamp to a datetime format.

For example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM articles 
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, FROM_UNIXTIME(created), NOW()) < 10 
LIMIT 2
```